Python: Have multiprocessing pools start and run their own multiprocessing pools
I am in the process of processing a list of arrays, and this is a workflow that could be parallelised at multiple points: One sub-process for each dataset in the list, and multiple sub-processes each to handle the different slices in the array.
I've read that process daemons are generally not allowed to spawn their own processes, and would appreciate advice on whether it's possible to overcome that limitation, and have sub-processes trigger their own sub-processes.
I've written a short example code for reference.
# Can a pool run their own pools?
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


def do_something(
    num: int,
    data: list[int],
    num_procs: int = 1,
):
    args_list = []
    for n in range(len(data)):
        args_list.append([data[n], num])
    with Pool(processes=num_procs) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(do_another_thing, args_list)
    return results

def do_another_thing(
    value1: int,
    value2: int,
):
    return value1 * value2

# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Example dataset of a list of arrays
    data = [np.random.randint(0, 255, (20)) for n in range(20)]

    args_list = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        args_list.append([i, data[i]])
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(do_something, args_list)

    for result in results:
        print(results)

Advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

There doesn't appear to be any threading in your example

Does multiprocessing.Pool not count as a thread? It is able to create daemon processes to run the functions in parallel. If there are other options that I could experiment with, I'm all ears!

multiprocessing.Pool manages a pool of processes - not threads

I see. I've clearly conflated the two things. I've correct my question now using the (hopefully) more correct terminology. Any suggestions on how I might get sub-processes in a pool to trigger their own sub-processes?

You probably want to use something like dask where you have one central scheduler that you can submit additional tasks from your current tasks. This page also gives you ways to think about structuring your computation that wouldn't require you to submit tasks from tasks, and therefore still be able to use something like multiprocessing. https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/task-launch.html
